# Simple algorithm to compute vertical map of set of segments?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

The paper [An optimal algorithm for intersecting line segments in the plane](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/IntersectLineSegments.pdf) by Chazelle and Edelsbrunner defines the "vertical map" of a set of segments as

> the planar subdivision obtained by drawing a rectangular frame around the
>   segments and connecting by a vertical line segment every endpoint to
>   the edges immediately above and below

(It really is easier to understand looking at the diagram on the top of page 3).

They make the comment

> we do not know of any *simple* algorithm, no matter how slow, for
>   computing the vertical map of a set of segments

To me this seems confusing, because I immediately thought of a simple algorithm to do so:

```
Iterate through every endpoint p
  Iterate through every other segment s
    t=intersection(s, vertical line through p)
    keep track of the closest t above and below p

  add the closest point above and the closest point below and connect them with a segment
```

And then we're done?  I mean, this would only be O(N^2) running time, not even that bad.

What more could they mean that this algorithm doesn't satisfy?  Do they expect to find the intersection points as well?  Wouldn't an O(N^2) pairwise intersection check do that?  Do they want to enumerate the subdivisions of the plane?  Couldn't that just be done very simply using standard algorithms to go from points+edges to faces? e.g. by walking around the border of the face?

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

The papers is from 1992, and - as an example -, the author works with C-code.

At that time, there was not (except perhaps in specific languages, but not fast, not easy to use and code), **collections, sort and other very sympathetic and optimized tools we have today.**

So, if you try to do it, **only with arrays and simple types,** you probably will need a lot of arrays, indexes and loops, and this will not be very easy to understand.

Note that the paper is plenty of process time, and memory usage.

Comment: 1. I am referring to the quote "we do not know of any simple algorithm, **no matter how slow**, for computing the vertical map of a set of segments", so certainly the slowness of my algorithm does not disqualify it. 2. The quote is about the algorithm to compute the "vertical map", and I wrote in my question what I understood it to mean.  If the "vertical map" is something else, please explain what it means, because I do not understand.

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina: I disagree. Theoretical papers in algorithmics establish absolute bounds on the complexity of the problems. These cannot be beaten. The generic data structures that are now built into standard libraries can make no improvement. On the opposite, as they are general purpose, all they can do is make it slower; and in many cases, they are not sufficient. By the way, all of the standard containers were invented in the 70's or before.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - the discussion is about "we do not know of any simple algorithm, no matter how slow, for computing the vertical map of a set of segments", even in O(n^2) which is the origin of this question, not the complexity of the algorithm itself. So what is a "simple algorithm" ? STL and collections were not coded in 70's.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina: are you sure ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust - OOP + generics + collections + high level of abstraction + fast execution is rather recent (20 last years). Before, it was not "simple".

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina: no, fast execution is not recent.